# How do I get 100 lists of numbers ,every list contains 5 floating numbers ranged from 1 to 5,but no repeats in each list

Tags: python, list

I’ve tried sample module to generate lists but only get 5 lists thought I need much more...what should I do?
There shall be no repeats in Each list
But the repetitive lists are allowed

Comment: Go through some tutorials. Learn about `list`, `loops` and `range` function. You will get there

Comment: Sounds like you want to shuffle and then split into evenly sized chunks for which there is a duplicate for the latter

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar thank you but I actually practice with tutorials guides and get stuck there...

Comment: @Sayse Not exactly but thank you at all, so kind of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When asking a question, make sure to provide examples of what you've tried and what output you're expecting.

If the output your expecting is 100 lists of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` see below:

```
import random

listAmount = 100
lists = []

for l in range(listAmount):

    lists.append([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

    #Shuffle the list:
    random.shuffle(lists[l])
    print(lists[l])
```

Comment: So kind of you to help a greenhand guy like me ! I will remember to paste my code and examples next time ~